# What is the difference between “concurrence” and “compétition”, and why?

Tags: sens, étymologie, comparaison-de-langues, latin

It always confounded me why Russian language borrowed the Western word “concurrence” (*конкуренция*) to mean “competition”. English *concurrence* means “coincidence” or “agreement” more often than not, which seems more suitable given the origins of the verb *to concur*, as per OED:

> **Origin:** late Middle English (also in the senses ‘collide’ and ‘act in combination’): from Latin *concurrere* ‘run together, assemble in crowds’, from *con-* ‘together with’ + *currere* ‘to run’

The only thing that hints on competition is the sense “collide” this mentions. Also, in the English-Russian dictionary [the entry for *concurrence*](http://slovari.yandex.ru/concurrence/en-ru/LingvoScience/#lingvo/) does list the sense of “competition”, although far from primary, but, at the same time, none of the major English dictionaries available on-line (OED, M-W, Cambridge, etc.) mention that sense, even as archaic (Mayhaps it can be found in un-abridged versions?).

Then it dawned on me that given the French influence on Russian culture in XVIII–XIX centuries, it could be the respective borrowing. And sure enough, those few definitions I had checked do list “competition” as primary and only meaning for French *concurrence*.

Why did French, along with Italian (*concorrenza*, although they still have *competizione*) and German (*Konkurrenz*) took that approach to this word while English and Spanish (*competición*) took what seems to be an opposite? I had also found the actual French *compétition* — which one of the two is more commonly used, or these are interchangeable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In French,

## Concurrence

Is used as a subject or object as *la concurrence*,

> *Dans le milieu des mathématiques, **la concurrence** entre chercheurs est féroce*
>   In Mathematics, there is **a** fierce **competition** between researchers

Here, it means indeed *competition*.

> *Ce traitre est passé à **la concurrence***
>   This traitor now works for **one of our competitors**

Here, it is the set of all the competitors ; primarily of a company, but by analogy it could also be a rival sports team, band…

It is also used in the prepositional phrase *en concurrence*, to mean that some entities are competitors, again, it is primarily for companies

> *Airbus et Boeing sont **en concurrence***
>   Airbus and Boeing are **competitors**

## Compétition

Has almost the same uses as *concurrence*, but is used primarily for non-business-related activities,

> *​Га́рри Каспа́ров et Анато́лий Ка́рпов étaient **en compétition** pour le titre de champion du monde d'échecs​*
>   Га́рри Каспа́ров and Анато́лий Ка́рпов were **competitors** for the world chess championship
>
> *Dans le championnat du monde d'escrime, **la compétition** est féroce*
>   **The competition** in the world fencing championship is fierce

But it can't be used to mean *the set of all competitors in a non-business-related challenge*, for that, one has to use *la concurrence*. Instead *la compétition* conveniently refers to the competition itself

> ***Une compétition** de jujitsu*
>   **A jujutsu** tournament

## Etymology

Actually, according to the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comp%C3%A9tition), *compétition* comes from the English *competition*, which comes from the Latin *con*+[*peto*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peto#Latin). *Peto* means, amongst many other meanings, “trying to reach”. Ultimately,  [it seems](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peto#Etymology_2) to trace back to PIE *peth₂- (“to fall; fly”), which gave *feather* (and then *pen*) in English.

On the other hand, *concurrence*, according to [the wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concurrence#.C3.89tymologie), is the Medieval Latin *concurentia*, which comes from the Classical Latin *concurrens*, present participle of *concurro*, for which I found **many** meanings in **many** dictionaries that seldom agree with each other

- According to the [Wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concurro#la) (fr.wiktionary), *concurro* has the only meaning of the French *concourir* (compete)
- According to [the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concurro), it means “running together”, “flock”… with no mention of competition
- According to [latin-dictionary.net](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/12173/concurro-concurrere-concurri-concursus), it means “charge”, “engage into battle”, “rally” or “run together”
- According to [Perseus Latin Word Study Tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=concurro&la=la#lexicon), it is “to run together, assemble, flock together”
- According to [Félix Gaffiot's dictionary](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=376) (and the [next page](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=377)) it has the three meanings of “running together toward a point”, “meeting” and “colliding”

I suppose that the meaning of *competing* comes from running challenges: several individuals running together toward a single goal, and that by extension it has come to mean the competition rather the act of running.

Comment: Good explanation of differences in usage of the two words, but are there authoritative sources as to _why_ different languages took on nearly opposite senses of the word _concurrence_?

Comment: I haven't found any so far. That's why I said “I suppose”.

Comment: I feel like you're wrong about something, is that "concourir" doesn't only mean "to compete" in french. It also means "to contribute" or  "to meet". https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concourir

Answer (score 3):

*Concurrence* doesn't always imply that there is a competition or a rivalry (but it doesn't imply either that there is none). It means that there are others (and the term also is used to designate them as a whole) who are trying to achieve the same goal and with whom you may collaborate or just be indifferent about their success or failure.

Now there is a second meaning where there is a rivalry. Looking at the historical notes of the [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/concurrence) one see that the second meaning is newer than the first.  And it doesn't really surprise me that the meaning of a word evolves so that it becomes more (or less in other cases) specialized.

Answer (score 2):

Le mot *concurrence* est utilisé quand plusieurs personnes ou organisations ont la même activité ou des activités similaires, chacun cherchant à être meilleur que les autres.

> **Exemple** : Dans un service, il y a le plus souvent de la concurrence entre les employés, mais il n´y a pas de récompense précise à la fin.

Le mot *compétition* est utilisé quand au bout d´une activité précise il y a une récompense à la fin.

> **Exemple** : Dans une course de 100m, les athlètes sont en compétition pour le titre final.

Comment: I don’t speak French, but from what I can make out, _concurrence_ talks about ongoing rivalry, so to speak, whereas _compétition_ means an event that has a conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

- Concurrence has the ultimate aim to eliminate the other.
- Competition does not aim for that. It has the aim to improve beyond the standards of the other, and hence it also contributes indirectly to the improvement of the other.

Comment: There is an error in the downvote due to me on this answer; it' s locked but it should be removed.